# Strange output from console with NPM v3

Tags: node.js, console, npm

Ever since I switched to npm 3 with node.js 5 my console output looks like:

[image: npm console output]

I'm using Menlo Regular for Powerline font.

❯ echo $TERM
xterm-256color

❯ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to uncheck the **Treat ambiguous-width characters as double width characters** setting in iTerm and restart the app.

**See iTerm > Preferences > Profiles > Text > Double-Width Characters**

The full-width progress bar was added in npm v3, causing this issue for many people. Credit goes to those participating in the discussion at:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9670

[iTerm Text Preferences Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJEwh.png)